# Booked Visa appointment before passport renewal

Tags: visas, usa

Please can someone help me. I made a visa appointment before I renew my passport. What should I do because my appointment is coming up and I have my renew passport but when I booked the appointment I use my old passport before the renewal. What should I do? It is a student visa

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need any help. For USA students visa you will have to appear for an interview.

At the interview you explain the situation to the consular officer and present the new passport. Carry both passports along. It should not be a problem.